# How to convert encoded video file to raw video format | OpenCV to read the raw file

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing, opencv3.0, image-compression

It would be appreciated If someone could guide me on:

1 - How do I can convert encoded video file **(.mp4)** to **raw video format.**

2 - How do I can read the frames of this raw video 
    file in the OpenCV library?

```
 eg: To read the .mp4 I can use - 
 cv::VideoCapture cap("abc.mp4");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just read the `mp4`?

Comment: Do you mean you want expand every single frame of your `mp4` out to its full lossless resolution and write them all to disk to make your file many, many times bigger? Why would you do that?

Comment: Hii Mark, OpenCV utilizes CPU to decode the frames from the mp4 file. I wanted to measure the performance of my application so I would like to have raw video file data instead of the encoded video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is very sensible (because of the file size involved), but it does what you ask.

```
# Generate sample movie with 250 frames of 640x480 pixels
ffmpeg -v warning -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=decimals=0:s=640x480:rate=25 -t 10 movie.mov
```

That looks like this (except this is a GIF with limited colours and framerate because of StackOverflow limitations):

[image]

```
# Check number of frames is 250
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 movie.mov
250

# Check size. It is 54kB
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff       54939 14 May 10:02 movie.mov

# Now make into raw BGR24 video
ffmpeg -v error -i movie.mov -pix_fmt bgr24 -f rawvideo -an -sn movie.bgr24

# Check size. It is now 230400 kB = 640x480 pixels of 3 bytes BGR at 25 fps for 10s
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   230400000 14 May 10:11 movie.bgr24
```

---

Now you can read it in OpenCV without doing any video decompression. C++ is not my forte, but this should work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int
main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
   std::ifstream file("movie.bgr24", std::ios::binary);
   unsigned int i=0;

   std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(640*480*3);

   while(file.read((char *)&buffer[0],640*480*3)){
      i++;
      std::cout << "Frame: " << i << std::endl;
      cv::Mat img(cv::Size(640,480),CV_8UC3,&buffer[0]);
      cv::imshow ("RAW", img);
      cv::waitKey(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your valuable input

Comment: I would like to have a mp4 file instead of movie.mov file. I can convert .mp4 file to raw video format by running "ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.yuv" command.

Comment: Now is it right way to convert yuv to bgr by using ->  "ffmpeg -v error -i out.yuv -pix_fmt bgr24 -f rawvideo -an -sn output.bgr24" ?

Comment: I only made the file `movie.mov` because you didn't provide a file! If your file is called `movie.mp4` just make it RGB24 raw  with `ffmpeg -v error -i movie.mp4 -pix_fmt bgr24 -f rawvideo -an -sn movie.bgr24`

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the quick reply. below code I am using to read the 
 frame from this file                                                                           
 fstream infile;
unsigned int i=0;
infile.open("movie.bgr24",ios::binary|ios::in);
unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[921600];
while(infile.read((char *)&buffer,sizeof(buffer))){
 cv::Mat img(Size(640,480),CV_8UC3,&buffer,640*3);
 imshow ("okay.jpg", img);

Comment: with the above code, I am getting a segmentation fault error. when trying to display the image by using imshow() function.

Comment: gdb log:   0x00007ffff777fd60 in icvCvt_BGR2RGB_8u_C3R(unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int, CvSize) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4

Comment: Just try simply reading the frames and see how many you get without putting them into a `Mat` for now please.

Comment: Also, you don't need the final parameter (stride) when you create your Mat - it is done automagically.

Comment: For movie.bgr24 (created file by referring the answer section, not from .mp4) while loop has executed "28800001" times. and without passing the stride value am getting the same issue.

Comment: I had a moment to look at this more closely - I don't use C++ much these days so my initial attempt was *"sub-optimal"*. It seems to work ok now. Apologies for the delay. Please have another look at the C++ stuff.

Comment: Hi Mark, The application is working perfectly. thank you so much for your valuable support. For learning purposes would you suggest any useful like for jjmpeg library?